# GraphIntersection Problem

Tags: intersection

I Have a problem when plotting 2 functions. I want to find out where the two graphs intersect eachother. That said, I want the coordinates (x, y) of the point.

```
p1 = Plot[2/(1 + 20 x^2), {x, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 16), GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 3}]

p2 = Plot[1/(1 + 20 x^2)^(1/2), {x, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 16), GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 3}]

Show[p1, p2]
```

When I'm using "GraphIntersection" I get this error:

```
GraphIntersection[p1, p2]
```

> "A graph object is expected at position 1 in GraphIntersection"

I'm pretty new to this, can somebody help?

Comment: Since you just want the coordinates of the point, you should use `Solve` instead. `Solve[2/(1 + 20 x^2) == 1/(1 + 20 x^2)^(1/2), x, Reals]`

Comment: Yes, thanks for the info! But what if I want to show this point in a graph?

Comment: In the context of mathematics a *graph* is usually understood to be a network of vertices and connecting edges (see, e.g. the [Graph documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html)), whereas what you call a graph is usually called a *plot* (or a line graph). So, `GraphIntersection` deals with intersections of graphs (as in networks) and has nothing to do with intersections of plot lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f1 = 2/(1 + 20 x^2);
f2 = 1/(1 + 20 x^2)^(1/2);

xp = FindInstance[f1 == f2 && 0 < x < 3, x, Reals, 15] // Values // Flatten
```

[image]

```
yp = f1 /. x -> xp
```

[image]

```
Plot[{f1, f2}, {x, 0, 3},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{First@xp, First@yp}]},
 LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 16),
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> {0, 3},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: @Einstein You're welcome. BTW, you can accept, upvote and downvote answers. Please study the stackexchange help :)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach is to use `Mesh` and `MeshFunctions` as follows:

```
ClearAll[f, g];
f = 2/(1 + 20 x^2);
g = 1/(1 + 20 x^2)^(1/2);
Plot[{f, g}, {x, 0, 3},
 MeshFunctions -> {(f - g) /. x -> # &}, Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]],
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 16),
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {0, 3}]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[f2, g2, x];
f2 = 3/(3 + 20 (Sin@x - 1/2)^2);
g2 = 1/(1 + 5 (Sin[x] - 3/10)^2)^(1/2);
Plot[{f2, g2}, {x, 0, 3}, MeshFunctions -> {(f2 - g2) /. x -> # &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]],
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 16),
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {0, 3/2}]
```

[image]

You can also find the mesh points by using `Solve` instead of using `MeshFunctions`:

```
mesh = Last @@@ N[Solve[{f2 == g2, 0 <= x <= 3}, x, Reals] ]
(* {2.7032,0.438392,2.29184,0.849753} *)

Plot[{f2, g2}, {x, 0, 3}, Mesh -> {mesh}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 16), 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {0, 3/2}]
(* same picture *)
```

**Update:** You can also use the function `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` to find the intersections in a graphics object:

```
plot = Plot[{f2, g2}, {x, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 16), GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 3/2}];

Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ FindIntersections[plot]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The function `GraphIntersection[]` is for graphs in the combinatorial sense, not function plotting sense, and seems to find the largest common subgraph of two graphs. So, `Solve[]` is your friend, as pointed out by @RunnyKine.

Comment: Actually it doesn't find the largest common subgraph.  It first takes *all* vertices from the two graph, distinguishing them by their label/name, then discards all edges except the ones that are present in both.  So this one: `GraphIntersection[Graph[{1 <-> 2}], Graph[{3 <-> 4}]]` gives 4 vertices and no edges (not a graph consisting of two connected vertices).

Comment: I think there's no function in Mathematica that finds the largest common subgraph for unlabelled graphs.